# Missing field 'uid' while computing key fields when used react mutation graphq

Tags: addtocart, graphql, ecommerce-tracking, react

[image]

[image]

Help me! Not add product with mitation, always show this error. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get the solution of this problem? I'm also stuck in a similar error in one of my GraphQL query.